# Modular way to work with form elements

Tags: forms, 8, theming

When rendering a simple form element:

```
$form['gender'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Are you a boy or a girl?',
  '#options' => array(
    0 => 'Boy',
    1 => 'Girl',        
  ),
);
```

We have

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'fieldset' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/fieldset.html.twig' -->
<fieldset data-drupal-selector="edit-gender" id="edit-gender--wrapper" class="fieldgroup form-composite js-form-item form-item js-form-wrapper form-wrapper">
      <legend>
    <span class="fieldset-legend">Are you a boy or a girl?</span>
  </legend>
  <div class="fieldset-wrapper">


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'radios' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/radios.html.twig' -->
<div id="edit-gender" class="form-radios">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/form-element.html.twig' -->
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-radio form-type-radio js-form-item-gender form-item-gender">


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'input__radio' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * input--radio.html.twig
   x input.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/input.html.twig' -->
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-gender-0" type="radio" id="edit-gender-0" name="gender" value="0" class="form-radio">

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/input.html.twig' -->




<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element_label' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/form-element-label.html.twig' -->
<label for="edit-gender-0" class="option">Boy</label>
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/form-element-label.html.twig' -->


      </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/form-element.html.twig' -->



<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/form-element.html.twig' -->
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-radio form-type-radio js-form-item-gender form-item-gender">


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'input__radio' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * input--radio.html.twig
   x input.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/input.html.twig' -->
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-gender-1" type="radio" id="edit-gender-1" name="gender" value="1" class="form-radio">

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/input.html.twig' -->




<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element_label' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/form-element-label.html.twig' -->
<label for="edit-gender-1" class="option">Girl</label>
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/form-element-label.html.twig' -->


      </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/form-element.html.twig' -->

</div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/radios.html.twig' -->


          </div>
</fieldset>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/fieldset.html.twig' -->
```

So we have 5 Twig templates. It's a lot of boilerplate code which I'm looking to get some control over.

Goals:

- Needs to be for a specific form
- Must be able to override these
  templates

Ideally, I would want to end up something like here:

```
<div class="gender">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" attributes>
    <label></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" attributes>
    <label></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" attributes>
    <label></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Something I would recognise to be good; Is being able to specify some attribute when defining the form element:

```
$form['gender'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Are you a boy or a girl?',
  '#options' => array(
    0 => 'Boy',
    1 => 'Girl',        
  ),
  '#theme_type' => 'foobar',
);
```

And then maybe override something like:

```
foobar--fieldset.html.twig
foobar--radios.html.twig
foobar--form-element.html.twig
foobar--input--radio.html.twig
foobar--element--label.html.twig
```

However having to override 5 templates are a lot, if there is anyway to simplify to only override the inputs, and then everything around would be sucifient.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I guess I need to use: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x

```
hook_theme_suggestions_alter
```

But form there I'm actually not sure how to accomplish these kind of suggestions.

```
function custom_test_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if (!isset($variables['element']['#theme_type'])) {
      return;
  }
  if ($variables['element']['#theme_type'] === 'quiz') {
    $suggestions[] = 'foo__bar';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is unfortunately really hard right now. The form theming is the biggest  part that was not refactored, menu templates e.g. got a lot simpler, but forms are still very complex.

Yes, hook_theme_suggestions_alter() is the right way, but first you need to be able to identify your elements there and more importantly, identify the form you're working with. That's not possible without some form alters, see [How can we find the id of the parent form in preprocess_HOOK() or HOOK_alter() theme functions?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211982/how-can-we-find-the-id-of-the-parent-form-in-preprocess-hook-or-hook-alter-t/211992#211992)

That hook also doesn't allow you to get rid of templates, only provide alternatives, so you still have those templates, the best you can do is remove the HTML so they're not printing out something anymore.

`radios` is also an especially complex case. Just like `checkboxes`, it actually expands itself into N #type radio form elements during rendering, thats why you end up with even more templates than usual.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, makes sense. However, when making the most simplest suggestion based on the related question you linked; It seems like it only suggests the fieldset and radios in this case. But the form_element and form_element_label and the input_radio does not get any suggest hooks. Are there anything special I need for that?
Updated question with the example in the bottom I just tried.

Comment: Ah, I noticed that the #theme_type I defined is not added onto the "child elements" of that form element. Is there any possibility to do that? Other only thing I can think of is adding some sort of defined prefix to the element, and then look in the "#parents" to see if it contains i.e. foo_ or something and then add that suggestion.