# Changing Twig template of form items through the theme

Tags: 8, theming

I have a block, which renders out a form using code that looks like this:

```
{{ attribute(form.facets, 'filter_' ~ filter.name) }}
```

I'd like to amend the markup and CSS classes for the various elements that are output, including fieldset, input, label etc. I appreciate that I can override the template files for fieldset for example, by creating a `fieldset.html.twig` file in my theme, but I don't want to change the markup for every fieldset element. I only want to apply my custom templates to form elements which are rendered out from a specific block.

I know that I can use a 'suggestion' (`mytheme_theme_suggestions_alter`) to alter the template for any element, but I can't see a way of determining if an 'input' for example, is an input within my block, or some other block on the site. Does anyone know how I'd identify this?

Comment: Did you already come across https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/211992/57183 and http://kevinquillen.com/drupal/2017/01/28/adding-twig-template-suggestions-for-form-elements?

Comment: I'd seen the second link, which I'd successfully used on another part of the site, but I hadn't seen that first link. I'm going to have a play with that now and see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`drupal_static()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/8.2.x) together with the following two hooks in your module or your theme to add template suggestions for input elements based on the block ID where the input element is used in (same would work with fieldsets or any other form/render element):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_block(&$variables) {

  $bid = &drupal_static('block_id', TRUE);
  $bid = $variables['elements']['#id'];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_input_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $bid = &drupal_static('block_id', FALSE);

  if ($bid) {
    $suggestions[] = 'input__block__' . $bid;
    $suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '__block__' . $bid;
  };
}
```

For example the search form textfield:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * input--search.html.twig
   * input--search--block--neato-search.html.twig
   * input--block--neato-search.html.twig
   x input.html.twig
-->
```

For example the password textfield:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * input--password.html.twig
   * input--password--block--userlogin.html.twig
   * input--block--userlogin.html.twig
   x input.html.twig
-->
```

Comment: Not sure about this @laymannx. It does do the trick, but using the global context to transfer information between functions is risky, think of a call to `drupal_static_reset()`. Additionally, calls to `drupal_static`, should be 'namespaced' by using the `__FUNCTION__` magic constant to use the function's name inside of which `drupal_static` is called, i.e. `drupal_static(__FUNCTION__)`, in that way making them specific to the function that needs them multiple times in the same request.

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis - Thanks a lot for your comment. I definitely have to dive deeper into `drupal_static` I learned of only yesterday. I will look how core or other contrib modules use it. Do you know of any other alternative to pass variables between hooks?

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately. Instead of `MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_block`, I was using `MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_form` and then trying to catch the `bid` in say `MYTHEME/MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_input_alter`. The problem was that the suggestion appears to run before the preprocess.

Comment: @laymannx - No worries, I think another option would be using session variables, but I would still go the way suggested in my first comment in the OP

Comment: @JamesThomson – `bid` means block ID. You probably won't get that in the form.

Comment: I changed it to grab the form ID. I could see the static var being populated in the preprocess, but only after the suggestion functions had already executed.

Comment: @JamesThomson – Indeed, I tried it myself. It doesn't seem to work for all forms at the same time on the page. For some I got the suggestion. For some I didn't got them. I guess then the solution in the comments under your question should be the way to go. Maybe you get it running and then can provide an answer yourself.